# Facebook PHP SDK won't detect user change on first refresh

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I have a small bug that's associated with Facebook log-in on my application.

Once a user is changing his account through the native Facebook site, and I am refreshing the page(which uses the facebook.php class) and call $facebook->getUser() it will still return me the user ID of the previous user, and will only update on the second refresh.

I have checked the permissions that we are requesting, and those that we were requesting in the past, and it seems that there is no 'Offline access' t here, so I have eliminated it from the list of possible causes.

This is important both from security and use convenience reasons.
I've tried calling destroySession, I have also tried killing the cookie manually by doing the following:

```
setcookie('fbsr_' . FACEBOOK_APP_ID, '', time()-3600, '/', '.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

What could be the reason for this odd behavior?, can some one please assist me?.

Thanks in advance,
Oleg.

complete code of the page:

```
<?php
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
require_once 'src/facebook.php';
require_once 'config/configFB.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
));


// Get User ID
$fbUserId = $facebook->getUser();
echo $fbUserId;//testing the bug
exit(1);
?>
```

IMPORTANT: all the users that I am using in order to test this scenario have added my application, so in fact, I'm supposed to have access to their data.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do a header redirect to the same page to "act" as the second redirect. More of just a band aide rather than a proper solution. Although unless im mistaken if I log into a different facebook account I will have to reauthorise your application to use that account because the permissions will not be set.

Comment: Yes you will have to authorize my application, unless you have already done it preciously, which is the case here.

Comment: So just to confirm, do you have to authorise the app when you change your account on the native facebook site?

Comment: If you have already authorized the app, you can just cann $facebook->getUser()

At least this is the way that it should be.

Comment: Yeh I was talking about first time. So if I log onto your website using facebook I would have to authorise the app, then if I went onto the native facebook site and logged in with a different account then went back to your site, I would have to authorise your app again for my second facebook account. 

Yeh sorry im not sure what is happening with yours. I tried it on a test app but it works fine with the same code and process.

Comment: both of the users that I am using for this test had previously added my App.
Thanks for making the effort to help me though